# How to deal with questions where the asker is trying to write code with questionable moral implications?

Tags: discussion, ethics

I've come across a couple of questions where the user is asking an on-topic, well asked question about how to solve a problem they are facing, but in the background to the question they reveal or imply it's to create a facebook bot or some sort of borderline malicious software, or even just something that *could* be used that way.
I understand some people might be set *create a password cracker* as a homework exercise or similar, and obviously if the question is unambiguously looking to commit a crime we can flag it... But is the potential ethical implications of a question something we should be considerate of?
Is that our place as answerers?
It feels wrong to flag an otherwise perfectly good question on this *might* be used for something bad, and I couldn't find anything in the code of conduct about it? I'm not sure what category I would flag such questions under anyway?

Comment: See [Dealing with questions of nefarious intent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent/) on Meta Stack Exchange

Comment: downvote it and don't give an answer

Comment: If the question is on-topic for this site and can be reasonably answered in our format, then it should be. There's nothing wrong with these questions. We cannot guess about the intentions of the askers, and we should not attempt to do so. Think of it this way: it's useful to the *good guys* to understand how the *bad guys* work. Explaining how a simple password cracker works is important to ensuring we programmers build systems with sufficient security and that we users follow good security practices.

Comment: If the question is *not* on-topic for the site, or cannot be reasonably answered in our format, then you should flag it as being in need of closure. Pick the reason from the list that is the best fit. If you can't find any reasons that fit, the question is probably not unsuitable for our site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We aren't the police, and we don't have the jurisdiction to enforce any laws.

If you believe the question is still on-topic and good, then there's no reason to flag it for what you *think* may be nefarious.  Remember:  "good" guys are also involved with questionably moral code.