Are there valid reasons for the "Other" close reason in the Staging Ground?
In the Staging Ground, I sometimes see questionable votes as off-topic (like using pretty much any of the close reasons in cases when "Requires Major Changes" would be more appropriate).
However, among the cases where I have seen the "Other" off-topic reason being used, it was only for cases like this where there was a lack of detail, the post was non-english or similar. All of these cases (I have seen) should have been "Major Changes" instead of voting it off-topic with a custom reason.
This begs the question: Is there any valid reason to mark a question as off-topic using the "Other" option or is it just a honeypot for bad closures? While the pre-specified close reasons are applicable in some cases (e.g. if the question seems to be fundamentally not about programming at all or is intrinsically opinion based, it's fair to close these questions but I don't see any way this would happen with the "Other" close reason.
I have written a user script for finding these comments and it seems like almost all of these comments should be "Requires Major Changes" (with this being an exception).
Here are some examples of comments that should (in my opinion) have been "Major Changes". In order to avoid these posts suddenly getting overwhelmed with reviews from the Meta effect, I am not adding links to the comments (I omitted e.g. the same comment happening multiple times):

I think that this topic is off-topic because it's not in English


I think that this topic is off-topic because it needs to clarify the problem and add additional details.


I think that this topic is off-topic because English is required for all content on Stack Overflow


I think that this topic is off-topic because not written in English


I think that this topic is off-topic because the OP is seeking to hire a developer. Stack Overflow is meant to help people resolve a specific problem or error in their own code. It is not a place to hire people or ask for someone to "write the codez"


I think that this topic is off-topic because it's asking for detailed help to do homework, without any effort.


I think that this topic is off-topic because it is too broad. If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.


I think that this topic is off-topic because it's asking for opinion based responses


I think that this topic is off-topic because is not an issue but the user is directly asking for other to the coding, is explained OP doesn't want to learn a new language and that makes the expectation others will just do the remaining work on his behalf


I think that this topic is off-topic because it's about removing a copyright notice


I used it once for non-question.

Fair point but to be honest, I think "Requires Major Changes" may be more appropriate because you don't actually know whether it's a work request or just lacking details.

Using my script, I found some other uses of the "Other" close reason that are along the lines of "It fits better on another SE site" but to be honest, I think these are mostly covered by the "Not about programming" close reason. Another thing is giving additional reasoning for a close reason (not about programming because) but that could also be done via an additional comment.

Yes, whenever the close reasons provided don't adequately cover (read: explain) the (valid) reason a question should be closed, rather than sent back for re-review. As Dharman's answer covers, it's a rare situation where it's needed. I haven't done a ton of SG reviews, but I think I've used the "other" reason only once.

I think "off-topic" is a bad label in the UI in the first place. It should be something like "duplicate or not fixable".

I think it's technically correct as off-topic votes in the SG should be used for questions that are inherently off-topic (IMO). But practically, I agree that people interpret that in a different way.

I can imagine that this close reason is used when a question asks for ways to bypass site rules or violate laws. I once saw a question on how to bypass a Telegram ban, I think the "Other" close reason would definaetly fit there.

The use of "other" close reason on the main site is very controversial. There are rarely, if ever, reasons to use it. Most of the time people use it incorrectly. Examples:

"I’m voting to close this question because it exhibits zero prior research." (Lack of research is not a reason to close a question)
"I think that this topic is off-topic because it's not written in English" (we already have a dedicated close reason for this.)
"You might find the computer science community a better place for answers." (that's not a reason to close a question on SO though)
"Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question seems to need more focus, in its current state it's not a concrete solvable programming problem but a broad requirement dump." (that's just feels like a misuse of the "other" option. The reason should be "needs focus" and if more explanation is required a comment can just be added after voting to close)
"Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you only provided a link to your website instead of code. Please read this Meta discussion about why we need the code in your question and [edit] a [mre] in." (That's "needs details or clarity" or "needs MCVE")
"Unfortunately, SO is not a code writing service. Please start with the [tour] and have a look at [ask]." (SO is a code writing service, it's mostly what we do.)

These are just some of the most recent ones. There are some which seem valid, but could just be bunched into the generic "not about programming", e.g. "I’m voting to close this question because this is not the LinkedIn support"
Staging Ground doesn't really need a feature that most of users don't know how to use and has little value. And since in SG we can stop the question from being posted by using "Major changes" options, why would we ever need a custom close reason. I say we should be using "Major changes" instead of "other" close reason all the time.

Let's analyse the examples you picked out from SG:

I think that this topic is off-topic because it's not in English

This should be "major details" because we expect the OP to rewrite the question into English

I think that this topic is off-topic because it needs to clarify the problem and add additional details.

Obviously "major details"

I think that this topic is off-topic because English is required for all content on Stack Overflow

Same as above.

I think that this topic is off-topic because not written in English

Same as above.

I think that this topic is off-topic because the OP is seeking to hire a developer. Stack Overflow is meant to help people resolve a specific problem or error in their own code. It is not a place to hire people or ask for someone to "write the codez"

That's spam. We treat requests to hire people as spam. Otherwise it should be "major details"

I think that this topic is off-topic because it's asking for detailed help to do homework, without any effort.

This just looks like the person who wrote that misunderstood how Stack Overflow works. I am not sure what lead someone to write this, but this seems obviously wrong. We don't require effort from people beyond the basic effort to write understandable question. If the question is homework, it needs a clear description of what part of the homework task the user is facing the problem with. If that's missing, it should be "major details". If the homework question clearly points out what needs to be done then what's the issue?

I think that this topic is off-topic because it is too broad. If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Should be "major details". They need to edit the question.

I think that this topic is off-topic because it's asking for opinion based responses

"Major details" or pre-existing close reason alternatively. Depends on whether the question can be improved or not. If it asks "what is your favourite programming language" it cannot be improved but if it asks "what is the best way to do X" then it should be "major details".

I think that this topic is off-topic because is not an issue but the user is directly asking for other to the coding, is explained OP doesn't want to learn a new language and that makes the expectation others will just do the remaining work on his behalf

What does that have to do with the question being on-topic though? Is the question answerable or not? If not, then it should be "major details".

I think that this topic is off-topic because it's about removing a copyright notice

Why is that off-topic? Are they not looking for a way to do this programmatically? If so then it's correct close reason.

The copyright one is for doing it programmatically. And yes, these things being used instead of "Major Changes" is the main thing that's annoying me.

I imagine this improper use of the close vote often has a fairly valid trigger (IMO), namely that the asker seems irresponsive to the "Major Changes" request. Indeed, that's part of what brings me here. E.g., I just saw this. So, that's 4 correct "Major Changes", and users seem to repeat those, because if they don't, their review doesn't "count". Not sure, but potentially the result is just an extension of the Q lifecycle.

Re: Non-English: We have a "Major changes" comment template for this, which is preferable to a close reason. It's not listed in the list of off-topic reasons for that reason.

Re "not a code writing service", they're not wrong. If someone says "please do my homework for me", we'll say no, and if a question is asking for too much, it can be closed as "too broad". But TBF I don't know how helpful that comment is since I don't have the context.

@wjandrea Yes, but that's not a reason to close a question in SG. The author just needs to specify which part of the homework task they have a problem with.

@Dharman Well yeah, if it's unclear what they're asking. But if they're literally saying, "Please do my homework for me", I would have no problem just saying no, though maybe more politely, like "Write your own code, but if you get stuck, then that could be a good opportunity for a question."

@ouroboros1 that one's partly on the reviewers and partly on the SG design IMO. They opened up (SG doesn't automatically direct you to posts in the Major Changes state) a post that was already marked as Major Changes, saw the comment left by previous reviewers, decided to post yet another duplicate comment and review it again with the same status. ¯\(ツ)/¯

"The copyright one is for doing it programmatically" - I'm (one of the persons) who posted the comment "I think that this topic is off-topic because it's about removing a copyright notice" - It's seems off-topic to me as it's unethical and was the breaking the ToS of the service used by OP. How/why should this be flagged with major changes? OP even stated "I don't want to pay for their subscription - Related staging ground question. How should these kind of questions be handled then?

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267699/how-do-we-handle-questions-that-are-potentially-or-blatantly-illegal-or-maliciou

See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397009/how-to-deal-with-questions-where-the-asker-is-trying-to-write-code-with-question

Still unsure what the correct action is though after reading the two answers. Especially because Robert Harvey stated: "Questions that clearly seek to defraud or otherwise harm are not allowed here.", if the linked question didn't have any mention about the service being used or not wanting to pay said service then sure I wouldn't have flagged it as off-topic

@DarkBee I guess you did the right thing in this case.

"You might find the computer science community a better place for answers. (that's not a reason to close a question on SO though)" - this could have come from someone who wanted to choose "not about programming or software development" for something that doesn't fit the on-topic guidelines but is about general computer science - and thought it would be strange to say that computer science isn't about programming.

Anyway, some questions really are irredeemably unfocused, because they're a homework dump. OP is perfectly welcome to choose a point on the assignment to ask about, and ask a proper question; but it would bear no apparent relationship to the original question, so it doesn't seem to me like a matter of "major changes". After all, on the main site, we disallow (at least in theory) "major changes" to a question to ask a completely different question.

Some of your examples of what you say are misuse of the "Other" reason on the main site - the "requirement dump" and "link to your website" ones - are cases where a canned close reason applies, but the close voter is choosing to give a reason more precisely tailored to the question at hand. I don't see a problem with that. Many of the stock closure reasons are vague, or have descriptions that don't quite match their titles, or list multiple only-kinda-related reasons for closure in one stock close reason. It's easy for newbies to be confused by them and unsure what to do. More clarity is good.

Using a custom reason is more confusing because the blue banner will say the question is off-topic while it's not. It just needs more details or focus.

@Dharman Wait, having gone hunting for questions closed with custom reasons, I'm pretty sure the phrase "off-topic" doesn't actually get used in the banner for them anywhere. Instead - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78203634/restoring-a-wrklnk-file - it says "Closed. This question does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines. It is not currently accepting answers.", then "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.". (Admittedly that's also confusing, especially since there's a separate "not about programming" reason...)

@MarkAmery Yes, sorry. I was referring to the "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center." sentence.
